# How does a "case" anonymous function really work in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Dеar Scala,

```
scala> val f1: ((Int, Int)) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }
f1: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2: (Int, Int) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }
f2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

huh?!

```
scala> f1(1, 2)
res2: Int = 3
```

Ok...

```
scala> def takesIntInt2Int(fun: (Int, Int) => Int) = fun(100, 200)
takesIntInt2Int: (fun: (Int, Int) => Int)Int

scala> def takesTuple2Int(fun: ((Int, Int)) => Int) = fun(100, 200)
takesTuple2Int: (fun: ((Int, Int)) => Int)Int

scala> takesIntInt2Int(f2)
res4: Int = 300

scala> takesIntInt2Int(f1)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int)) => Int
 required: (Int, Int) => Int
              takesIntInt2Int(f1)
                              ^

scala> takesTuple2Int(f1)
res6: Int = 300

scala> takesTuple2Int(f2)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: ((Int, Int)) => Int
              takesTuple2Int(f2)
```

Right. And now, look at this!

```
scala> takesTuple2Int { case (a, b, c) => a + b + c }
<console>:9: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: (Int, Int)
              takesTuple2Int { case (a, b, c) => a + b + c }
                                    ^

scala> takesIntInt2Int { case (a, b, c) => a + b + c }
<console>:9: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: (Int, Int)
              takesIntInt2Int { case (a, b, c) => a + b + c }
```

Like, **srsly**? o_O Both result in `required: (Int, Int)` error.

Why then use `case` at all in such anonymous functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See section 8.5 of the Scala reference (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf). The expression `{ case (a, b) => a + b }` is interpreted differently based on the expected type. In your definition of `f1` it created a `PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int]` which was cast to a `Function1[(Int, Int), Int]`, i.e. `((Int, Int)) => Int` whereas in the definition of `f2` it created a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`, i.e. `(Int, Int) => Int`.

These two interpretations relate to the two situations where you would commonly use case in an anonymous function.

One is for writing anonymous functions that accept tuples and work on their components, as you did with `f1`. An example would be the function you pass to the `foreach` or `map` method on a `Map`, e.g. `Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4) map { case (k, v) => k + v }`.

The second is for writing an anonymous function that does a `match` on its sole parameter. Your `f2` is doing this, but not in any useful way. An example would be the anonymous function passed to `collect`, e.g. `List(1, -2, 3) collect { case x if x > 0 => -x }`.

Note that the two can be combined, that is functions like `f1` can do complex matching as well. For example, `Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4) collect { case (k, v) if k < 2 => v }`.

Edit: `res2` works because of tupling. If an application doesn't type check, the compiler will try wrapping the args in a tuple before failing.

But that is tried just for applications; it's not a general conversion, as you discovered.  It will not try to upgrade a value `Function2[A, B, C]` to `Function1[(A, B), C]`.

Comment: It would be great to be able to do all this without using `case` keyword. Why the difference in syntax for Function and PartialFunction, from normal developer's point of view?

Comment: @MichałRus To be honest, this always did bother me a bit. Haskell and Clojure have much simpler syntaxes for expressing pattern matching directly on a function's parameters.